# Pycharm не запускает файлы

Tags: python, pycharm

В какой-то момент при попытке запустить любой файл начала появляться вот такая ошибка как на скрине (красное окошко снизу). Пробовал уже переустанавливать пичарм - не помогло. Может ли быть проблема в папке с подписью library root? Я так и не смог понять для чего она нужна, но основная папка, в которой у меня все файлы хранятся, это папка Python. Может как-то можно переназначить это library root, или проблема не в этом?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Папку меняли? Попробуйте запустить через Ctrl + Shift + F10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте разместить файл с исходным кодом в пути, не содержащим каталоги на русском языке, только на латинице.

Comment: так-то конкретно этот файл на скрине у меня так и размещен, у него путь Desktop/Python/файл. Да и до этого с кириллицей проблем не было. Но вот конкретно файл сейчас переименовал на латиницу и помогло, спасибо. Придется теперь всё переименовывать

Comment: Вообще, к сожалению, практика показывает - кириллицу следует избегать. Даже название файла на русском языке может вызвать недоумение у IDE, компилятора или интерпретатора. Так что латиница, де-факто стандарт наименования и файлов и каталогов